# how to return one value after condition

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php function.it's check current time is in which field.then it's retrive the cost for that range.

field structure : from(time) - to (time)- Cost

```
+---------------------+---------+--------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| id_delivery_week    | weekday |specific_time_cost_1     | specific_time_cost_2     | specific_time_cost_3   |
+---------------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
|                   1 | Sunday | 00:00:00-10:00:00-130.00 | 10:00:00-18:00:00-120.00 | 18:00:00-24:59:00-150.0
```

below is my function to check cost for current time.

**Edit**

```
//user can pick day from drop down.picked day will receive in to `getData()` 
    protected function getData(){
          if(isset($_GET['day']) && !empty($_GET['day'])){ 
            $day=$_GET['day'];
            $now = new DateTime();
            $Date = $now->format('Y-m-d');
            $time = $now->format('H:i:s');
            $this->checkCostRanges($day,$time);
          }
        }



protected function checkCostRanges($day,$time){

    $ranges=$this->getCostRanges($day); //mysql select query

    foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    if ((!empty($range['specific_time_cost_1']))){
      $shipping_cost=$this->calRange($range['specific_time_cost_1'],$time);

    }
    if ((!empty($range['specific_time_cost_2']))){
      $shipping_cost=$this->calRange($range['specific_time_cost_2'],$time);

    }
    if ((!empty($range['specific_time_cost_3']))){
      $shipping_cost=$this->calRange($range['specific_time_cost_3'],$time);

    }
  }
}
```

$time :- this is current time (eg : 12:08:53)

$range :- all 3 ranges (specific_time_cost_1,specific_time_cost_2,specific_time_cost_3)

```
public function calRange($range,$time){
      $cost_val="";
      $parts = explode("-", $range);
      $from = $parts[0];
      $to = $parts[1];
      $cost = $parts[2];
      $curr_time = is_int($time) ? $date : strtotime($time); // convert non timestamps
      $from_time = is_int($from) ? $from : strtotime($from);
      $to_time = is_int($to) ? $to : strtotime($to);

      if(($curr_time > $from_time) && ($curr_time <= $to_time)){//check current time is in which field
        $cost_val=$cost; //get cost for the field
        error_log("inside if ".$cost_val);
      }
      error_log("outside if ".$cost_val);
      return $cost_val;
    }
```

inside the `if` condition,i can get correct cost for current time.according to example time,i can get `120.00` . because `12:08:53` is in `specific_time_cost_2`.

but out side if return;

" ",120.00," " (first empty value,then correct value,again empty value)

how can i return only correct value?

Comment: How is that even possible that this particular function returns " ",120.00," " with a given input data? It is not possible. Do you run this function in loop or what?

Comment: yes it's comming from a loop (mysql select query).i have edited my question

Comment: Your `checkCostRanges` function is wrong, you are missing a `}`
And show us where you are calling `checkCostRanges`

Comment: Thanks.please check my edited question

Comment: That is an awful database design. You should normalise your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the results. If for instance you have a match with the first time range, you still process the second time range and then clear the previous result. So do something like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
  if (!empty($range["specific_time_cost_$i"])){
    $shipping_cost = $this->calRange($range["specific_time_cost_$i"],$time);
    if ($shipping_cost !== "") break;
  }
}
```

Note however that you are using a badly designed database. You should instead store the ranges in a separate table, where you would have a foreign key reference to the main table, the sequence number of the range (e.g. 1, 2 or 3), the start time, the end time and the cost, all as separate fields. That will make the processing a lot(!) easier, as it will allow you to find the matching time ranges even with a simple SQL query.

Comment: That makes no sense. At least 2 possible unwanted if evalutaions, why wont you simply return first valid value ( !== "") or default?

Comment: Sure, this code can be improved, but I did not want to give the impression this design has any future. This is just patchwork. The OP should really start from scratch and redesign the database. I have updated the answer now in a way to avoid code repetition. But I do not claim that this is in any way efficient. The database must be redesigned. I don't feel like investing time to make this work better without such redesign is well-spent effort.

Comment: @trincot thanks .it's working.yes understood i have to re design my db structure.thanks again for your advices.